# unexpected token import (webpack es6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack

i am trying to bundle es6 modules with webpack. I have done everything written here http://www.zsoltnagy.eu/using-es6-modules-with-webpack/ but error still exist. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty old article, the babel has been updated from that time, so you have to

- create file .babelrc
- add presets to support necessary features

Full list of necessary information can be found in the official docs: https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/31/setting-up-babel-6